# What is the appropriate way to return a variable from another namespace::method using a dispatch table

Tags: perl

#### code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '/home/user/perl/lib/';

use SQLConnect;

my $db_something = SQLConnect->newConn({dns => "SOMETHING"});

my $sql_data = $db_something->select_fetchallArray();

for my $row ( @{$sql_data} ) {

    print ",";

    for my $column (@{$row}) {
        print $column . ",";
    }

    print "\n";
```

#### SQLConnect.pm (personal)

```
sub newConn {
    my ($class, $args) = @_;

    my $self = bless {
        dns      => $args,
        user     => myINIconfig::ini_dbUser($args->{dns}),
        password => myINIconfig::ini_dbPass($args->{dns}),
    }, $class;
}
```

Is this the appropriate way to return a variable using a dispatch table? The variables I am trying to return live in my `iniConfig` package, which contains a method to parse an `odbc.ini` file for the username and password to our SQL databases. I am receiving the following error:

> Can't use string ("SOMETHING") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use.

```
sub ini_dbUser {
    my $self = shift;

    my $dbh = ( $self->{dns} );

    open( INI, "$path$ini" ) || die "Can't open $ini: $!\n";

    while (<INI>) {
        chomp;

        next if /^\s*#/;    # ignore comments
        next if /^\s*;/;    # ignore ;

        if ( /^\s*[\s*(.+?)\s*]\s*$/ ) { }

        if ( /^\s*([^=]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?)\s*$/ ) {

            if ( ( $database eq $dbh ) && ( $keyword eq "username" ) ) {
                $user = $value;
                print "$user\n";
            }
        }
    }

    close(INI);
    return ($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting confused about levels of hash indexing

First of all, your constructor `newConn` is being passed a reference to a hash `{dns => "SOMETHING"}` for the value of `$args`, which you then use directly when you create the object in the element `dns => $args`. That means you are setting it to `dns => {dns => "SOMETHING"}` which doesn't look at all right

Then you're extracting the value of the `dns` element of `$args` when you call `myINIconfig::ini_dbUser($args->{dns})`, so you're calling `myINIconfig::ini_dbUser("SOMETHING")`. But `ini_dbUser` first copies that parameter to `$self`, and then tries to use it as a hash reference in `my $dbh = ( $self->{dns} )`. Hence your error message `Can't use string ("SOMETHING") as a HASH ref`

I can't tell what is correct, but changing the call to just `myINIconfig::ini_dbUser($args)` will at least get it working

Your use of `$self` implies that `ini_dbUser` is an object-oriented method, but you're calling it as a simple function. Is that perhaps the problem?

Comment: By updating this: myINIconfig::ini_dbUser($args), my hash should actually pass this to my DBI->connect:  dns => dbhandle, user=>username, password=>password. Right? Once my sub ini_dbUser process the argument that is.

Comment: @user6788226: I can't tell. You don't show a call to `DBI->connect`.

Comment: my $dbh = DBI->connect('DBI:ODBC:'.$self->{dns}, $self->{user}, $self->{password},
                        {RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 0})
                            or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr . "\n";

Comment: There are lots of moving parts to this. We're running on version 5.8.5, otherwise, I would have used one of CPAN's ini packages.

Comment: The plan here was to get away from 1) and go with 2)

1)
my $db_bareports = SQLConnect->new({
dns => "DBHANDLE",
user=> "report_user",
password=> "mypass"
});
2)
my $db_bareports = SQLConnect->newConn('DBHANDLE');

Answer (score 0):

ini_dbUser is expecting to be passed `$args` (a hashref with a `dns` key), not `$args->{dns}`.

This also looks wrong:

```
my $self = bless {
    dns      => $args,
```

That is setting `{ 'dns' => { 'dns' => 'SOMETHING' }, ...`

Comment: sub newConn in SQLConnect.pm (listed above) is not returning a variable when using myINIconfig::ini_dbUser($args->{dns}) as the hash value. Am I loading this incorrectly?